# Why doesn't this simple jQuery script work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

First the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    <!--
    <?php
    echo("var answersC = 'answertable'+$qrow->id;");
    echo("var toggleC = 'toggletable'+$qrow->id;");
    ?>
    jQuery('#'+toggleC).click(function() {
    jQuery('#'+answersC).slideToggle('fast');
    });
    console.log('#'+toggleC); //example #toggletable6
    console.log('#'+answersC); //example #answertable6
    // -->
```

I posted this in another thread to workout how to use the variables for the id name, but now that is working properly with no errors... ***but also no result***.

**Details:**

- This script sits within the PHP page that renders an admin page for a
  WordPress plugin.
- It is within a loop of results and the intent is to
  toggle the display of a list of answers on a question by question
  basis based on a unique id.
- I use a nearly identical bit of script
  that successfully will display all answers to all questions based on
  their common class.
- I have verified that the div ids are showing
  properly in the html and the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
)};
```

or put it at the end of your `body`.  Otherwise, the code gets run before your element exists so no handler gets added.